# Move the cursor to an empty cell within a Google Sheet row

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Exactly I want to write a script that finds an empty cell in a row and enters today's date.

But I don't know how to automatically select blank spaces in a row.

The rest of the functionality I needed was covered by conditional formatting.

But I've never learned how to write a script.

Please help me.

Comment: Ctrl+ right arrow ?

Comment: How to you propose to trigger this script? How is one to know which row is to apply?

Comment: `I've never learned how to write a script.` It's not that hard - you might start here - [Build web apps and automate tasks with Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)